# Windows Socket Programming -> Delay in messages getting transfered in some systems

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I have a client-server model software which uses Windows sockets for communication. It works absolutely fine on most windows xp systems and windows 7 systems. But on some XP and 7 systems, there is always a delay in the time taken for the message to reach from client to server and vice versa. I checked the logs, and it suggests that the message has left the client, and the server log shows it receives the data after a long period.

In the systems it works, time taken is few milliseconds, but in the ones it doesn't work it is about 20-30 seconds.

Has anyone faced any issues such as this? Or can anyone suggest what I can do? Maybe some environment settings or so ?

All systems tested with are 32 bit systems. (Tested with latest computers as well, so it is not an issue of say maybe slow computer)

Comment: Have you tried `tracert` to see if you have a routing issue? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326

Comment: @RogerRowland Client and Server are on same machine for testing purpose